# Motivating the definition of a morphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry

I'm trying to give a motivational explanation for why morphisms between algebraic sets $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$ is defined the way that it is defined, that is, that it is the set of polynomial maps $\mathbb{A}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^m$ restricted to the domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. Many texts simply say that it is natural to define morphisms between varieties to be polynomial maps between algebraic sets, because algebraic sets are zero loci of polynomials, but I just cannot seem to get to the point where I feel myself "getting it", so to speak. Therefore, I have been trying to come up with a motivational explanation of my own. But here to, I run into problems.

Now, let's say that $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$ are algebraic sets. Then that means that $X$ and $Y$ are the zero loci of some set of polynomials $f_i \in K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ (call it $T$) and $g_i \in K[y_1 , \dots , y_m]$ (call it $S$). Let's say then that we have a map $\varphi : \mathbb{A}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^m$, and let's ask what conditions we need to put on it to make it a morphism $X \rightarrow Y$.

$\varphi$ then induces a map from the set of functions $\mathbb{A}^m \rightarrow K$ (denote it $\mathcal{F}[\mathbb{A}^m]$) to the set of functions $\mathbb{A}^n \rightarrow K$ (denote it $\mathcal{F}[\mathbb{A}^n]$), $\varphi^{*} : \mathcal{F}[\mathbb{A}^n] \rightarrow \mathcal{F}[\mathbb{A}^m]$, by $g(y_1 , \dots , y_m) \mapsto f(z_1 , \dots , z_n) = g (y_1 (z_1 , \dots , z_n), \dots , y_m (z_1 , \dots , z_n))$.

We want our morphism to be such that points in $X$ are mapped to points in $Y$. Since $Y = \{ (y_1 , \dots , y_m) \in \mathbb{A}^m | g_i (y_1 , \dots , y_m) = 0 , \forall g_i \in S \}$, this then means that we will have $g_i (\varphi(x_1 , \dots , x_n)) = 0$ for all $(x_1 , \dots , x_n) \in X$, and so $X$ may be described as $X = \{ (x_1 , \dots , x_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n | g_i (\varphi (x_1 , \dots , x_n)) = 0 , \forall g_i \in S \}$.

Now this is the point at which I am struggling.

It is known that the zero locus of general functions $h_i : \mathbb{A}^n \rightarrow K$ is not necessarily an algebraic set. For example, the set $\{ (x,y) | y - \sin^2(x) = 0 \}$ can be shown not to be algebraic. If I could show that we need to have $\varphi$ be a polynomial map for the $\{ (x_1 , \dots , x_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n | g_i (\varphi (x_1 , \dots , x_n)) = 0 , \forall g_i \in S \}$ to actually define an algebraic set, I would basically have the whole definition justified.

The problem is, though, I don't really know how to go about doing that. Is that even possible? Can I find non-polynomial $\varphi: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $\{ (x_1 , \dots , x_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n | g_i (\varphi (x_1 , \dots , x_n)) = 0 , \forall g_i \in S \}$ still defines an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^n$? Do I need to add further requirements?

As always, any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the explanation is much simpler than you're making it; we consider polynomial mappings because *we are interested in studying polynomial mappings*.

Comment: Yes, well, you see, the problem is that I don't really *get* that explanation.

Comment: What I am trying to ascertain is why a structure preserving map between the zero loci of two sets of polynomials would necessarily have to be a polynomial mapping.

To put it another way, let's say we want to give a definition for a morphism between groups. Then we would say something like "well, the structure of a group is determined by how different elements act on another. So let's say we have two groups $G$ and $H$ and wish to define what a morphism between them would look like."

Comment: "Then we would want to have that if $g_1 g_2 = g_3$, then we should want to define a morphism to be a mapping $\varphi$ such that $\varphi (g_1) \varphi (g_2) = \varphi(g_3)$, that is $\varphi$ carries with it the structure of multiplication of elements." What I am trying to do is to construct a similar line of reasoning for morphism between algebraic sets to make it all work in my head.

Comment: The answer to your question in your last paragraph is trivially yes: Just consider any map $X=\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^m=Y$ that's not algebraic. What you're missing is the requirement that the maps into the field are algebraic, in which case the motivation is the same as in the case of topological or smooth manifolds.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little further, thanks?

Comment: @StormyTeacup: I'm saying the motivation here is, in large part, exactly the opposite direction -- it would be more like we thought group homomorphisms were interesting, so we invented groups to help study them!

Comment: Linear mappings leading to the idea of vector spaces might be a better example, since one is likely to encounter various kinds of linear transformations before one conceive the idea of the abstract vector spaces to study them.

Comment: Huh. That's a very interesting way of looking at things indeed! Though I feel I need to ask you to explain how a set of points that are zero for a set of polynomials are the "vector spaces" if polynomial maps are the "linear transformations"?

Comment: @StormyTeacup: The nullspace of a linear transformation is a vector space. And often something we want to know about the linear transformation!